# Generating arithmetic expression string for given list of values and given result Prolog

Tags: prolog, arithmetic-expressions

I have the following problem. I need to write program which is generating arithmetic expression for given list and result value in Prolog. For example if I run something like this -> "expr([1,2],3,X)." it should give me result X=1+2. `3` in this query is result of expression which I'm looking for. I wrote some lines of code and always I got false as a result. My code is below (UPDATED):

```
expr([X], _, Expr, Val2):-
   integer(X),
   append(X,"",Expr),
   Val2 is X.
expr([X|Tail], Val, Expr, Val2) :-
    expr(Tail, Val, Expr1, N),
    \+ N = 0,
    Val2 is X / N,
    append("(", Expr1, Expr2),
    append(Expr2, ")", Expr3),
    append("/", Expr3, Expr4),
    append(X, Expr4, Expr).
expr([X|Tail], Val, Expr, Val2) :-
    expr(Tail, Val, Expr1, N),
    Val2 is X * N,
    append("(", Expr1, Expr2),
    append(Expr2, ")", Expr3),
    append("*", Expr3, Expr4),
    append(X, Expr4, Expr).
expr([X|Tail], Val, Expr, Val2) :-
    expr(Tail, Val, Expr1, N),
    Val2 is X - N,
    append("(", Expr1, Expr2),
    append(Expr2, ")", Expr3),
    append("-", Expr3, Expr4),
    append(X, Expr4, Expr).
expr([X|Tail], Val, Expr, Val2) :-
    expr(Tail, Val, Expr1, N),
    Val2 is X + N,
    append("(", Expr1, Expr2),
    append(Expr2, ")", Expr3),
    append("+", Expr3, Expr4),
    append(X, Expr4, Expr).

expr(X, Val, Expr) :-
    permutation(X,Perm),
    expr(Perm,Val,Expr,N),
    N = Val.
```

What I'm doing wrong? 
Is there any better solution for my problem?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: One problem right off is `[Head, X, Tail]`. That's a list of *exactly* three elements. Did you mean for it to be a list which has `Head` and `X` as the first two elements and then a tail, `Tail`? That would be `[Head, X | Tail]`. And what does the query, `expr([1,2], 3, X).` mean? You're saying the result would be `X = 1 + 2`. What if I queried, `expr([1,2], 2, X).`? Is it supposed to yield `X = 1 * 2` (some operation using `1` and `2` that yields `2` as a result)? It's a bit unclear how you want this to work overall.

Comment: Yes, I want get something like what you wrote. Query `expr([1,2], 3, X).` mean that I'm looking for expression which is fulfilled as `1 expr 2 = 3`. I know it is a bit trivial example but easy to analyse.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. See my comments about your list management, however, as that still seems to be an issue.